# React Native Application can't build on MacOS

Tags: xcode, react-native, macos, apple-m1

I have an Imac with M1, 16G, and i'm trying to build a react native project using Xcode.

Here are all the version i'm using:

[image]

I have this error message when I enter in my react-native application folder

[image]

My pod install fail with this error message

[image]

And the Build automaticly fail when i start the project.

[image]

I try to follow th step of the react native documentation:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli`

I don't know why but when I tried this it just say "already up to date" and do nothing.

The only thing i find to generate a working project is to set the react-native version to 0.68.2 but my project is working on 0.70.1

If someone has any solution, I'm open.

Comment: try to install pod like - `pod install --repo-update`.

Comment: Hi, I still have the same problem